# How to present a product as mine when it contains private/sensitive information?

Tags: freelance-websites

I've recently completed a job that I would like to show in my resume or website, mostly as a testament to my skills and of course self-promotion. My data contains private information that, if found published, may create a dispute with my client. I don't want to sour our relationship over something like this but I need to promote myself.

I was thinking of just changing the names of the different features and of course the client's name and change the private data (I've thought some montecarlo simulations or such) but it's such a sensitive subject (mining industry) it may be falsely interpreted by any common onlooker.

Any suggestions are well received.

TLDR: How to publish a website to serve my business ends without compromising my clients trust by publishing sensitive data?

Comment: Do you mean 'sensitive' information/subject/data?

Comment: Anything wrong with removing the logo, and replacing all the text with Lorem Ipsum?

Answer (score 1):

If you signed any sort of NDA (non-disclosure agreement), you are prohibited from publishing company-sensitive data.

If static screenshots with sensitive data redacted won't help you with your portfolio, you need to discuss with someone in authority in the company to give you permission to display some minimal amount of data so you can present what you need to present without exposing your client.

You have an inherent right to display your work in your portfolio (at least under United States copyright laws).